# How do I make pi = 3?

Tags: analytic-geometry, pi

This question emerges from a discussion on quora which concluded that if a circle was drawn on the surface of a sphere, the ratio of radius (from the circle's centre as projected to the sphere's surface, measured over the surface of the sphere) to the circumference could be made to equal exactly 1:3  So there is a "world" in which pi is actual a rational integer.

Q.  What is the required ratio of diameter of the sphere to the diameter of the circle for this to happen?

Comment: Note that on a sphere, the ratio between the circumference of a circle and its radius depends on the radius. If the radius is half the circumference of the sphere, the circle degenerates to a point, ratio $= 0$. Let the radius become smaller, the ratio grows, when the radius is a quarter of the circumference of teh sphere, the ratio is $2$, and if you shrink the radius further, the ratio approaches $\pi$.

Comment: $\Pi$ can be just about anything you want! Not sure if you are in the USA, but there have been several attempts by the government to pass law to establish mathematical and scientific facts. The most famous is when the state of Indiana almost passed a law making $\pi=3.2$ under the title: "A Bill for an act introducing a new mathematical truth...". See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Answer (score 2):

If you take the unit sphere $r=1$, denoted by $S^2$ and take the circle's center to be the north pole $n=(0,0,1)^T$, you want to know the diameter of the circle to be such that $\pi \cdot d = 3$ so $d = \frac3\pi$. From that you can compute backwards the height of the hyperplane $H:= \{x\in\mathbb R^3, x_3 = h\}$ such that $H\cap S^2$ yields this circle of diameter $\frac3\pi$